# How to set up passwordless ssh between two remote machines using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

The three computers involved are

- A: my desktop
- B: a non-aws server
- C: an aws EC2 instance

I would like to control data transfer from B to C, but I don't want to distribute my aws key from A to B. So the plan is to set up passwordless ssh from B to C by executing some code on A.

Specifically, what I did is to

1. Download the public key of B to some temporary file on A
2. Append that key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` of C

The code is here, the reason I use python is because there are other tasks this code need to deal with and python is more convenient than shell scripts

```
_, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
os.system('scp B:~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub %s' % path) 
cmd = 'cat %s | ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i %s %s "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"' % (path, my_aws_credential, C)
os.system(cmd)
os.unlink(path)
```

Is this an acceptable solution? Is there better way to do it? Is it possible not to download B's public key as a file to A?

Thank in advance.

Comment: If possible, use `ssh-copy-id`. Best not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a step back, and scoping the objective (please forgive me if I'm misinterpreting things). Communication between B & C is communication between B & C, which can be independent of A: if you remove that constraint, then it simplifies the things.

For AWS (or GCP, etc.), you can manage access control via IAM & roles. Therefore, if you set up the interaction between B & C via IAM, and have a different roles/service-accounts than you would between A & C, then the communication between B & C is controlled to your specifications. Your A machine can still control machine B, but now it's a different paradigm - that control structure can be its own ssh key exchange (you could lock out incoming access to B to nothing except A), or some sort of bool communication protocol within your python program.

Wrapping up, create the control construct you want between B & C first via AWS IAM, and then create the (independent, yet "triggered" or access/bool) protocol between A & B and you'll achieve the objective. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I assume IAM role for non-aws machine (i.e., B)?

Comment: Yes. The good new is _there's a lot of documentation that covers this_ [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingIAM.html#UsingIAMrolesWithAmazonEC2Instances) and [also here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-service.html) ...the bad news is _there's a lot of documentation that covers this_ . You'll definitely have to play around with creating roles and then assigning them to allow users/machines to connect. Also insure your firewall rules allow the other machine to connect. Good luck!